# what did I do wrong with my arrow function? It says function not defined

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm cloning the tetris game. And I defined an arrow function. To define the shape movement.when I run it. it told me that shape is not defined. what did I do wrong?

I'm trying to make drop movement inside the shape function. would that be doable?

```js
let Piece = new shapes(pieces[0][0], pieces[0][1]);
//import shapes from shapes.js

shapes = (shape, color) => {
    piece = shape;
    color = color;

    orientation = 0; //initial the shape from position 0;
    activePiece = piece[orientation];

    //position of the shape
    x = 3;
    y = 1;

    draw = () => {
        for (row = 0; row < activePiece.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < activePiece.length; col++) {
                if (activePiece[row][col] == 1) {
                    drawSquare(x + col, y + row, color)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    moveDown = () => {
        y++;
        draw();
    }

    // let drop = () => {
    //     moveDown();
    //     requestAnimationFrame(drop);
    // }
}

Piece.draw();
Piece.moveDown();
```

Comment: You are calling the function before it's created.

Comment: [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) shapes function to make use of it on importing the file

Comment: also arrow function can not be a constructor